# Dropbox HTTP API always returns "not currently allowed to use API v2."

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am just trying to get the HTTP API to work in any way at all. These are the steps I followed:

1. Created an app associated with my Dropbox account with "file type" permission. My app is listed under https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps when I'm logged in.
2. Used Dropbox's "generate" button from app info page to generate an access token.
3. Went to API explorer - https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#files_list_folder . The point of using this client tool is to rule out problems based on my incorrect use of the API.
4. Pasted my access token into the form. Set path to "/". Clicked "submit call" button.

I receive the following error:

```
Error: 400
Error in call to API function "files/list_folder": Your app is not 
currently allowed to use API v2.
```

In fact, every API call I try and whatever parameters I use give the same error message.

What can I do to fix this problem and use the HTTP API?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204873863-HTTP-API-Your-app-is-not-currently-allowed-to-use-API-v2- ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was necessary to delete the app and create again (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/create), this time specifying "Full Dropbox" permission type for the app. Dropbox API v2 doesn't currently support the "file type" permission which I had used the first time the app was created. The app's access token then worked with calls to methods in the API explorer.

Thanks to Gregory at Dropbox for the answer that I am passing on here for posterity.

Comment: Is it possible that v1 token when used, above exception is thrown as I am seeing some of users facing above mentioned problem